# Capitalizing Words Within a title

Tags: capitalization, titles

Could someone please tell me if "That" should be capitalized in the following title:

Learn the Winning Formula That Ironman Triathletes Use to Create Unstoppable Sales Success

Comment: No, I wouldn't capitalize *that*.

Comment: Bread - why do you say that?